# How to get list of sent emails in smtp virtual server in iis 6.0 on windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis-6, smtp

How to get list of sent emails in **smtp virtual server** in iis 6.0 on **windows 2003**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable logging. In the advanced tab (see article below), enable them all, and hopefully that will have the information you want to capture. Experiment with the results to refine what you need. If it is not enough, I am not sure what else you could do. It is a very basic SMTP mailer.

Great article here: http://www.msexchange.org/tutorials/Logging_the_SMTP_Service.html

If this worked for you, please return and mark the answer as accepted (click the check mark).